# Open Specific data using id in url in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to open the new page, which displays more details of data when the user clicks on the Read More button.

This is the component which displays in the homepage, and there is Read More button when the user clicks on it, it opens a new page with more detail of this component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Code(props) {

  const {desc, type, id } = props;
    return (
        <>
          <div className='box'>
            <h2 className='is-size-4'>{desc}</h2>
            <div className='detail'>
              <Link to={`code/${id}`} className='button btn'>
                <i className='fas fa-chevron-right'></i> &nbsp; Read More
              </Link>
              <div className='is-size-6 has-text-weight-medium tag'>Type: {type}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

And this is URL "http://localhost:3000/code/1"

I have added some few static data, just for UI,

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Navbar1 from '../layouts/navbar1';
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/StateManager';

export default function CodeDetail() {
    const { deleteCode } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar1/>
            <div className='section'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='box'>
                        <div className='title'>Grapes</div>
                        <pre>
                            font-family: Consolas,"courier new";
                            color: crimson;
                            background-color: #f1f1f1;
                            padding: 2px;
                            font-size: 105%;
                        </pre>
                        <div className='del-edit'>
                            <div className='button is-danger' onClick={deleteCode}>Delete</div>
                            <div className='button is-warning'>Edit</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to configure your route similar to the below snippet

```
<Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/code/:id"  component={CodeDetail} />
    </Switch>
```

If you want to pass props to a component, try using the render method

```
<Route path="/code/:id" render={(props) => <CodeDetail {...props} data={someSliceOfState}} /> } />
```

Comment: Yes I have also done that in App.js, and page is opening with static data but I dont know how to transfer the specific data from state, according to id

Comment: It looks like your Code component is receiving `id` as props.